# Transferring the value of an input to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a simple calculator, but I do not know how to transfer the value of an input into another.

```
    <table>
         <input type="text" id="screen"><br><br>
         <input type="button" value="1" id="digit">
         <input type="button" value="2" id="digit">
         <input type="button" value="+" id="operator">
        <input type="button" value="=" id="operator">
    </table>
```

This is my html code. I have 2 digits and 2 operators.
Now I want to write a code that will write the  value of the pressed digit in the screen input.
This is my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var number = '';
   $(this).click(function(){
   number= $(this).val();
   $('#screen').val(number);
   });
})
```

Comment: when you write html you must keep these things in mind. id attribute must be unique, class attribute need not be unique. id attribute must be used to retrieve value from an element. class attribute must be used to apply styles.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many mistakes in your code:

1. The first mistake you are doing is you **cannot repeat `id`s**. They should be unique.
2. Secondly, that is not a valid HTML. You cannot have those inside a `<table>` tag directly!
3. Thirdly, the `eventListener` you are using makes no sense.

What you might need would be something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $("#screen").val($("#screen").val() + " " + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="screen" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="1" />
<input type="button" value="2" />
<input type="button" value="+" />
<input type="button" value="=" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here:

- The `input` elements must be contained within a `<td>` in the `table`, which itself must be in a `<tr>`
- You need to actually select an element, you can't use `this` to do what you require within scope of the `document`.
- You've got duplicate `id` attributes on several elements. Use `class` to group elements together instead.
- The global definition of `number` is redundant.

Once you've fixed those issues, your code works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.digit').click(function() {
    var number = $(this).val();
    $('#screen').val(number);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="screen"><br><br>
      <input type="button" value="1" class="digit">
      <input type="button" value="2" class="digit">
      <input type="button" value="+" class="operator">
      <input type="button" value="=" class="operator">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```